# Parse JSON from Api to pandas dataframe with doubled names

Tags: python, json, pandas, api

I'm parsing a json and I don't understand how to correctly decompose it into a dataframe.

Json structure i have (api response):

```
{
  "result": {
    "data": [],
    "totals": [
      0
    ]
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-11-25 15:19:21"
}
```

response_ =

```
{
   "result":{
      "data":[
         {
            "dimensions":[
               {
                  "id":"2023-01-10",
                  "name":""
               },
               {
                  "id":"123",
                  "name":"good3"
               }
            ],
            "metrics":[
               10,
               20,
               30,
               40
            ]
         },
         {
            "dimensions":[
               {
                  "id":"2023-01-10",
                  "name":""
               },
               {
                  "id":"234",
                  "name":"good2"
               }
            ],
            "metrics":[
               1,
               2,
               3,
               4
            ]
         }
      ],
      "totals":[
         11,
         22,
         33,
         44
      ]
   },
   "timestamp":"2023-02-07 12:58:40"
}
```

I don't need "timestamp" and "totals" - just "data". So i do:

```
...
response_ = requests.post(url, headers=head, data=body)
datas = response_.json()
datas_ = datas['result']['data']
df1 = pd.json_normalize(datas_)
```

I got:

|  | dimensions | metrics |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [{'id': '2023-01-10', 'name': ''}, {'id': '123', 'name': 'good1'}] | [10, 20, 30, 40] |
| 1 | [{'id': '2023-01-10', 'name': ''}, {'id': '234', 'name': 'good2'}] | [1, 2, 3, 4] |

But i need dataframe like:

|  | id_ | name_ | id | name | metric1 | metric2 | metric3 | metric4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-01-10 |  | 123 | good1 | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 |
| 1 | 2023-01-10 |  | 234 | good2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

When i try like:

```
df1 = pd.json_normalize(datas_, 'dimensions')
```

i get all id's and name's in one column.

Explain step by step if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
response = {
    "result": {
        "data": [
            {
                "dimensions": [
                    {"id": "2023-01-10", "name": ""},
                    {"id": "123", "name": "good3"},
                ],
                "metrics": [10, 20, 30, 40],
            },
            {
                "dimensions": [
                    {"id": "2023-01-10", "name": ""},
                    {"id": "234", "name": "good2"},
                ],
                "metrics": [1, 2, 3, 4],
            },
        ],
        "totals": [11, 22, 33, 44],
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-02-07 12:58:40",
}

tmp = [
    {
        **{f"{k}_": v for k, v in d["dimensions"][0].items()},
        **{k: v for k, v in d["dimensions"][1].items()},
        **{f'metric{i}':m for i, m in enumerate(d['metrics'], 1)}
    }
    for d in response["result"]["data"]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(tmp)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
          id_ name_   id   name  metric1  metric2  metric3  metric4
0  2023-01-10        123  good3       10       20       30       40
1  2023-01-10        234  good2        1        2        3        4
```